# Angular2/Angular-cli strange errors when building with the --prod switch

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently updated angular-cli to 1.0.0-rc2 and all seemed to go well except I can't build my app with the --prod switch.  I am using the ng2-spin-kit module for loading indicators and it keeps complaining about not being able to find the module for each component of the ng-2-spin-kit module.  Any idea what could be going wrong here?  How could I resolve this?

## UPDATE

So it turns out the issue is that the latest version of angular-cli sets the --aot (ahead of time compilation) flag to true by default and some of my components aren't optimised for aot compilation...  Any idea how I could update all my components to be accepted for ahead of time compilation?  I don't mean the ng2-spin-kit.  just my app specific components, it turns out most of my components are optimised for aot even though I didn't intend for them to be while writing them...

```
my app.module.ts:

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CircleComponent } from './components/loader/spinner/circle.component';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './Components/product/product.component';

import { CheckBarcodesComponent } from './Components/check-barcodes/check-barcodes.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './Components/navigation/navigation.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './Components/settings/settings.component';
import { StockTransactionItemComponent } from './Components/stock-transaction-item/stock-transaction-item.component';
import { StockTakeComponent } from './Components/stock-take/stock-take.component';
import { LoaderComponent } from './Components/loader/loader.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './Components/error/error.component';
import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './components/goods-received/goods-received.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from './services/local-storage.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { StatusComponent } from './Components/status/status.component';
import { StringToDatePipe } from './pipes/string-to-date.pipe';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    CheckBarcodesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    StockTransactionItemComponent,
    StockTakeComponent,
    CircleComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    GoodsReceivedComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    StatusComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    StringToDatePipe    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RestService,
    LocalStorageService,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ng2-spin-kit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-spin-kit

my error/output:

```
   {0} polyfills.34c267ddff87908e0732.bundle.js (polyfills) 157 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.8abb16adf25a257394ee.bundle.js (main) 534 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.dde47148c4c3cb36c6df.bundle.js (scripts) 226 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} styles.7c25a02a137df81c1ced.bundle.css (styles) 122 bytes {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.608820e6096d2310322a.bundle.js (vendor) 2.46 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.077315b77d1f4e6e0707.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../loader/loader.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 26:0-65
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../error/error.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 29:0-63
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../error/error.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\components\goods-received'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts 45:0-63
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../navigation/navigation.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 44:0-73
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../navigation/navigation.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\components\goods-received'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts 47:0-73
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/loader/loader.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './spinner/circle.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm\src\$$_gendir\app\Components\loader'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/loader/loader.component.ngfactory.ts 22:0-65
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/settings/settings.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\rtm>
```

Comment: IS  'RotatingPlaneComponen' component declared on your module ?

Comment: @Gili Yaniv  See my update above

Comment: Can you share your appModule?

Comment: @Gili Yaniv I just added my app.module.ts...  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Try to check your main.ts file and see if you bootstrap you module. Should be like:
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); Also try to add your appComponent as export and entry point. 
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  exports: [AppComponent],

Comment: @Gili Yaniv my main.ts is correct, not sure what you mean with the app.component entrypoint?  i've never seen that before in any angular2 app?

Comment: @Gili Yaniv I updated my error/output in my questions.

Comment: I've added an example as an answer so it will be clearer... Try to add it to your appModule and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the normal, the 'Component' doesn't need anything special to support aot, but the module needs. The reason of your error is because the module you use `ng2-spin-kit` doesn't support AOT. You can see this [issue](https://github.com/WoltersKluwerPL/ng-spin-kit/issues/41) to say the error about AOT.

You can update that spin module. About how to support AOT, you can Check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#source-code).

Comment: I ended up not using the spin kit and copying the ng-2-spin kit's circle component into my code but still getting the same errors...  It seems like it's only complaining about components that are user by other component views e.g. my navbar and loader